# Office integration pack on web browser

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I get the below error when i try to export excel from  web browser based lightswitch using office integration pack :

File Operation not permitted. Access is denied

Is there is any way to export the excel from the lightswitch running in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the Office Integration Pack in a browser based app. You will need to write custom code to write out a `.csv` or an OpenXML Spreadsheet. Alternatively you could use SQL Server Reporting Services.

See [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dfa8ab28-720b-4598-8c86-daf16069a438/export-to-excel-from-web-application-is-it-possible?forum=lightswitch) for more details.