# Export to Excel from a LightSwitch HTML client

Tags: c#, html, lightswitch-2013

Because a lot of the **LightSwitch** posts in the web are related to the deprecated silverlight desktop applications and not **HTML 5 client applications**, I hope you can help me to get the **current technology status** right, here.

My target:

- **export data from a query** (handling parameters) to a rather complex (multiple sheets, maybe predefined charts) Excel spreadsheet
- **as little code as possible** (means: I do not care to develop a datastream and construct HTML headers and stuff like this, but it would be nice to have this in a library)
- **possibility to use templates** and just fill it with data
- **Visual Studio 2013 compatible**
- **No additional installations on the user side**: the user should just be able to download an Excel-File
- server/development environment is **IIS 7**, **MS SQL**, Microsoft **Visual Studio 2013**

I found:

- [Office Integration Pack](http://officeintegration.codeplex.com) -> **[NO GO]** [Stackoverflow post: it is deprecated for web browser apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646208/office-intgration-pack-on-web-browser)
- [Microsoft Report Viewer](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3248/Creating-Reports-in-LightSwitch-HTML-Client.aspx) -> looks good, but have to try it out to see if it works for templates
- [SQL Server Reporting Service](http://www.lightswitchspecial.com/2012/06/end-to-end-sql-server-reporting-service.html) -> only found old posts, probably not the quickest option for the HTML client
- [Telerik Reporting](http://tlrk.it/keOuIm) -> **[NO GO]** probably not supporting HTML clients anymore
- [Active Reports example](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3249/Creating-LightSwitch-HTML-Reports-using-ComponentOne-Active-Reports.aspx) -> looks to be actively developed, may be worth an investment (it is commercial)
- [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/) -> Would have been one of my favorite choices (from what I heard) but [they do not support LightSwitch HTML client](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q488892), and it seems like they in general do not continue LightSwitch support at all.
- [OpenXML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670141/Read-and-Write-Microsoft-Excel-with-Open-XML-SDK) -> impressiv OpenSource project, allows templates, needs some coding efforts but looks trustworthy
- [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/) (based on OpenXML)
- [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com) (based on OpenXML) -> did not find any LightSwitch examples, but probably nice on the server side

*My thoughts:*
Currently I am heading for OpenXML:

- active project
- documentation available (up-to-date examples)
- read somewhere about templates

Thank you, if you know other ways to go, or let me know if have experiences with one of those tools.

regards
Spikey

Answer (score 0):

I have used SQL Reporting Services, and it is a little long winded to set up as you stated but once you have it is very useful with LightSwitch HTML

from Lightswitch itself when you have generated the report I use the following code to download an exact version of the report to a PDF format. this can be done for excel files to. this is just on the execute code of a button

```
var InvoiceNum = screen.Invoice.InvoiceID;
window.open("http://yourservername/ReportServer_databasename/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fInvoice&rs:Command=Render&InvoiceID=" + InvoiceNum + "&rs:Format=PDF");
```

this passes the relevant information straight from the database via Lightswitch and to the report. remove this: `"&rs:Format=PDF");` if you wish to view the report in the browser window. This way you can choose to save the report to which ever format you want. I thought I would include that extension mind as I found it extremely useful.

be sure to note that the `/ReportServer_databasename` is essential for download them as I found out. using just `Reports_databasename` means that the extension on the end does not work.

link to file extentions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms154040.aspx

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog post (not a member of MSDN so unfortunately was not able to vote up)
https://hgminerva.wordpress.com/2012/05/28/how-to-export-data-to-csv-using-microsoft-lightswitch-web-application/

It solved the problem beautifully. There was an updated version also posted in C# here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e5f0d29d-5133-4297-8d59-33a208bda903/removing-controlavailable-after-adding-controlavailable?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e5f0d29d-5133-4297-8d59-33a208bda903/removing-controlavailable-after-adding-controlavailable?forum=lightswitch

The 3rd answer down also solves a small issue with exporting multiple pages.

ALL credit to [hgminerva](https://hgminerva.wordpress.com/author/hgminerva/) for the original VB and [Otis Ranger](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/otis%20ranger/?ws=usercard-mini) for the update and C# version